# Как объединять таблицы БД в запросе вертикально?

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Допустим, что нам нужно выполнить что-то в роде такого запроса,
где `с1` это и `table1.с1`, и `table2.с1`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c1) FROM table1, table2
```

Можно ли объединять таблицы БД в SQL запросе вертикально,
чтобы соответствующие столбцы рассматривались как единый столбец `[1, 1, 2, 2]`?

```
table1       table2       result
c1 c2 c3  +  c1 c2 c3  =  c1 c2 c3
1  1  1      2  2  2      1  1  1
1  1  1      2  2  2      1  1  1
                          2  2  2
                          2  2  2
```

Comment: [union](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте операцию [UNION](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL)):

```
<запрос1>
UNION [ALL]
<запрос2>
UNION [ALL]
<запрос3>
 .....;
```